# Склонение мужской иностранной фамилии

Tags: склонение

> ...Графиня бросила недоверчивый взгляд на Максима де Трай.

"Бросила недоверчивый взгляд на Максима де Трай"
(Бальзак "Гобсек")

Почему фамилия несклоняема?

Comment: Владимир, ваша любовь к художественной фотографии не добавляет к вопросу ничего, кроме мучений для читающих с телефона.  И еще. Предлагайте свою версию, Если она интересная - обсудим. А на каждую ошибку невесть какого автора спрашивать "почему" - идея не самая продуктивная.

Comment: Любовь к художественной фотографии на вопросы распространять не следует как где-то прописано в Справке. На ответы — можно.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> Де Трай  — персонаж из романов Бальзака «Гобсек», «Беатриса», «Цезарь
>   Бирото», «Кузина Бетта» и др. — великосветский авантюрист.

Такой Вам попался перевод. Скорее всего, и другие источники повторяют первый перевод "Гобсека" -  [Наталии Немчиновой. Оноре де Бальзак «Гобсек» / «Gobseck» (1949, повесть)](https://fantlab.ru/translator2157) (смотрите, где и когда она родилась и где и когда училась).

> Немчинова Наталия Ивановна (1892-1975) – родилась в Оренбурге. В 1917
>   г. окончила Бестужевские женские курсы в Петрограде, затем Московский
>   институт новых языков (1932).
>
> Печатается с 1934 года. ***Выполненные Н. Немчиновой переводы*** романов
>   Стендаля «Пармская обитель», О. Бальзака «Шуаны» и «Гобсек» , Э.
>   Золя «Жерминаль», Г. Мопассана «Монт-Ориоль» ***принадлежат к образцам
>   советского переводческого искусства.***
>
> Н. Немчинова переводила и современных французских писателей: романы Ф.
>   Мориака «Дорога в никуда» и«Клубок змей» , Ф. Эриа «Семья Буссардель»
>   (кн. 1), Э. Базена «Змея в кулаке» и «Семья Резо» (1-й т. дилогии), а
>   также произведения других авторов.

Современный анализ текста:

[Прекрасно разбираясь в людях, он оценивает их без­ошибочно и быстро. Впервые увидев **Максима де Трая**, Гобсек «прочел на его лице всю будущность графини» де Ресто. Максим де Трай и графиня де Ресто ради денег «готовы с головой окунуться в грязь». Даже у Гобсека они вызывают брезгливое чувство.](http://iessay.ru/ru/writers/foreign/b/balzak/stati/gobsek/klienty-gobseka-o-povesti-gobsek-o.-de-balzaka)

Нет причин не склонять фамилию на согласный.

[Дервиль, так и не получив встречной расписки о фиктивности сделки, узнает, что граф де Ресто тяжело болен. Графиня, чувствуя подвох, делает всё, чтобы не допустить стряпчего к мужу. К этому моменту графиня уже убедилась в подлости **Максима де Трая** и порвала с ним. Она столь ревностно ухаживает за умирающим мужем, что многие склонны простить ей прежние грехи — на самом деле она только хочет получить наследство.](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%93%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BA)